# Change div-order in colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to know if it's possible to change the div-order in [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)? I just ask because the cboxTitle-div is inside of the cboxContent-div. But I want the cboxTitle-div to be inside of the colorbox-div.

From this...

```
<div id="cboxContent">
    <div id="cboxTitle"></div>
</div>
```

to this...

```
<div id="colorbox">
    <div id="cboxTitle"></div>
    <div id="cboxContent"></div>  
</div>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't this be changed in your php?

Comment: Colorbox uses its own js-library. Under normal circumstances you should not modify that file if you want to change the stacking order and that kind of stuff. So my initial thought was if there was another way to reach that goal without modifying the js-file.

Comment: ahhaaaa... its a plug in. I haven't used it. no options in displaying?

Comment: Problem solved. See my comment below. Thanks anyway!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write one line of jQuery that would solve this and move the element:

```
$("#cboxTitle").appendTo("#colorbox");
```

Comment: Thanks.:) I'm tired and I will check this out tomorrow. I hope it will work!

Comment: Works!:) You saved my day!:D The code looks like this now:
onComplete: function(){
 $("#cboxLoadedContent").appendTo("#cboxContent");   
}

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do this but you could rearrange it with jQuery with the append method

```
$('body').append( '<div id="colorbox"></div>' );

$('#colorbox').append( $('#cboxTitle') );
$('#colorbox').append( $('#cboxContent') );
```