# is it possible to add an Image as Logo colorbox

Tags: javascript, css, colorbox

I have started to use Colorbox  http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ as image gallery. Everything works perfect. Now I would like to add an own image-logo at the bottom of my open colourbox. If somebody clicks on the logo it should go to the main page.

Does anybody has a good idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it can be done. Are you using inline colorbox or iframe ?

Comment: Dear Ani, thanks for your fast reply. I'm using colorbox as inline.

Comment: Just add the logo in the inline html then..What's going wrong for you ?

Comment: the exact comand of java

Answer (score 0):

Here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9M5k/)

```
    <p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a></p>

    <!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
    <div style='display:none'>
        <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
                   <p><img src="http://jquery.org/resources/members/intel.png" width="20%" />                      </p>

                 </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks again Ani. If I put this code into my code it display "Inline HTML" also at the main page. But there, there should not be displayed :-(.

Comment: what do you thin about this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238329/change-div-order-in-colorbox

.appendTo

Comment: Should work...But I am not sure what can't you hide the "Inline HTML" using css.